# I'm getting newsletters to an address I removed

Tags: support, newsletter

I'm getting newsletters from do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email to an address that I've removed from my account.

Why? Is my account not connected to the newsletter system?

I get the feeling my old address is stuck in places I don't know about...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your email preferences, in your profile preferences page:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current

You may find out that it is set to your old email address.